# OCR of PDF in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, azure

I have document library with more 20K PDF. which actually are scanned copies. Now I need to OCR these pdf as well as make provision to run any new upload through OCR. So that these pdfs can be come under the content search results.

Also, while searching I find one Azure solution name Azure Form Reader. Anybody has tried it for OCR the SharePoint Document?

Comment: This article can help you make pdf content searchable in sharepoint, [Make PDFs Searchable (OCR) After Importing into SharePoint](https://blog.developer.adobe.com/make-pdfs-searchable-ocr-after-importing-into-sharepoint-1a8037744841)

Comment: If you don't have adobe subscription and only Azure or Microsoft subscription. Then try Azure Cognitive Service + Power Platform + SharePoint. Reference Articles, [Azure Cognitive Service for Language](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/details/shared_cognitiveservicestextanalytics/azure-cognitive-service-for-language/), [Extract paragraph or sentence from pdf azure cognitive search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/641186/extract-paragraph-or-sentence-from-pdf-azure-cogni)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider looking at Microsoft Syntex which is part of SharePoint. It provides [unstructured document processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/syntex/document-understanding-overview) which can read [text or scanned PDFs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/syntex/requirements-and-limitations#unstructured-document-processing).

Comment: Microsoft Syntax doesn't not do the OCR for scanned content.

Comment: Yes, it does. From the second documentation link in my answer, there is a condition: "If scanned from paper documents, scans should be high-quality images."